# Jupyterhub Custom Authenticator

Tags: python, jupyterhub, authenticator

I am a little stuck with writing a custom authenticator for jupyterhub. Most probably because I do not understand the inner workings of the available [REMOTE_USER authenticator.](https://github.com/cwaldbieser/jhub_remote_user_authenticator/blob/master/jhub_remote_user_authenticator/remote_user_auth.py) I am not sure if it is applicable in my case... anyhow... this is what I'd like to do:

**My general idea:** I have a server that authenticates a user with his or her institutional login. After logging into the institution server/website, the users' data are encoded -- only some details to identify the user. They are then redirected to a the jupyterhub domain in the following way
`https://<mydomain>/hub/login?data=<here go the encrypted data>`

Now, if a request gets sent like this to my jupyterhub-domain, I'd like to decrypt the submitted data, and authenticate the user.

**My trial:**
I tried it with the following code. But it seems I am too nooby... :D 
So please, pedantic comments are welcome :D

```
from tornado import gen
from jupyterhub.auth import Authenticator

class MyAuthenticator(Authenticator):
    login_service = "my service"
    authenticator_login_url="authentication url"
    @gen.coroutine
    def authenticate(self,handler,data=None):
        # some verifications go here
        # if data is verified the username is returned
```

My first problem... clicking the button on the login page, doesn't redirect me to my Authentication URL... it seems the variable `authenticator_login_url` from the login template is set somewhere else...

Second problem... a request made to .../hub/login?data=... is not evaluated by the authenticator (it seems...)

So: Has somebody any hints for me how to go about this?

As you see I followed the tutorials here: 
https://universe-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authenticators.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the following code does the job, however, I am always open to improvements.

So, what I did was redirect an empty login attempt to the login-url and deny access. If data is presented, check the validity of the data. If verified, user can login.

```
from tornado import gen, web
from jupyterhub.handlers import BaseHandler
from jupyterhub.auth import Authenticator

class MyAuthenticator(Authenticator):
    login_service = "My Service"

    @gen.coroutine
    def authenticate(self,handler,data=None):
        rawd = None

       # If we receive no data we redirect to login page
       while (rawd is None):
           try:
               rawd = handler.get_argument("data")
           except:
               handler.redirect("<The login URL>")
               return None

       # Do some verification and get the data here.
       # Get the data from the parameters send to your hub from the login page, say username, access_token and email. Wrap everythin neatly in a dictionary and return it.

       userdict = {"name": username}
       userdict["auth_state"] = auth_state = {}
       auth_state['access_token'] = verify
       auth_state['email'] = email

       #return the dictionary
       return userdict
```

Simply add the file to the Python path, so that Jupyterhub is able to find it and make the necessary configurations in your `jupyterhub_config.py` file.